# Why are my Administrative Privileges Removed on a Daily Basis?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

My question is concerning **Administrative Privileges**.

Over the past few months, I've been randomly removed from the Administrative Group on a daily basis (3-4 times a week to be precise).

I'm currently an administrator on our SharePoint site

> Permission Level: Site Admin Full Control.

I am not a Site Collection Administrator and I cannot become one either.  I've begun to log my actions each time this error occurs.

1. Editing slides within a slide library
2. Editing an excel document via Excel Web App
3. Creating an App (i.e. Document Library) and placing it onto a site page
4. Editing site pages on other subsites within our site

I've also been removed after performing other actions, or just simply logging in, however, I've failed to record those occurrences.

No other user within the administrative group is experiencing these problems.  I've done some research and I have not found any mechanisms or security feature that automatically removes users from administrative groups.

Please help...thanks in advance!

Comment: SP2013 enviroment?

Comment: Are you mean you are member in local administrative group in AD ? and you disabled to achieve administrative tasks in your site although you already have a full control permission

Comment: Thank you for responding, and forgive me for the vague questions.  I am speaking about my SP 2013 environment.  I am not an administrator w/in AD.  I am only a site administrator on our SharePoint site.  I'm removed a SharePoint administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen something similar happen to me a while ago.

I don't have an exact answer but I like to think that permissions don't get removed by themselves.

Some ideas:

- You seem to work with On-Prem SharePoint, which means you probably have a team responsible for managing the system (BackOffice)
- If you are not Site Collection admin, you should be able to escalate the issue and have it looked by upper management
- There are scripts available online that admins like to run to erase all administrator permissions from sites on a regular basis
- Some systems have synchronization tools that could be running all the time and removing your permissions
- I find it unlikely that your permissions are removed because you performed a content management operation on X or Y
- [Audit Logs](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-audit-settings-for-a-site-collection-f5a346d0-ee0f-4412-a5e6-d9b5abaa1012?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) can be enabled to try and get some more details on who did what and when, especially if it happens often, you'll find out in no time
- Alternatively, considering you are not Site Collection admin, you could try and create a different group or event assign permissions directly to see if the the problem is that particular group

Comment: I have a script that removes SPD access every night.  If an SCA forgets to remove it, the risk is removed by the next day.

Comment: Thank you everyone who responded.  @Tiago Duarte, I've set up an Audit Log to track any changes with my permissions.  If--more like when--my permissions are changed, I'll hopefully be able to identify what is the cause.